Is the extension $\mathbb Q(X^2) \subset \mathbb Q(X)$ Galois?
So $\mathbb Q(X)$ is the field of rational functions and
$\mathbb Q(X^2)$ is the field of rational functions but the polynomials are in the $X^2$ variable and we have
$\mathbb Q(X^2) \subset \mathbb Q(X)$
I haven't been able to advance in this problem, I think that we should show that there is a separable polynomial $f$ in $\mathbb Q(X^2)[x]$ such that $\mathbb Q(X)$ is the splitting field of $f$ but I haven't figured out which one. Any help is appreciated.

The polynomial $f(x)=x^2-X^2 \in \mathbb{Q}(X^2)[x]$ satisfies $f(X^2)=X^2-X^2=0$. As we are in characteristic zero we get that our extension is separable. Thus, you are left to check that the extension is normal too. However, in $\mathbb{Q}(X)[x]$ the polynomial splits.

I guess you can finish from here. It would be great if you could write out an answer. Then you can check whether you really understand what is going on and get feedback from other users. Furthermore, it might help future visitors of this site.

thank you, I think i'm not used to work with weird fields such as $\mathbb Q(X)$ so that's why I couldn't think of a polynomial. I'll write a solution.

Since you mention "weird fields such as $\mathbb{Q}(X)$", maybe it will help your intuition to know that $\mathbb{Q}(X) \cong \mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ (or indeed, $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ where $a$ is anything transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$).  So in fact, $\mathbb{Q}(X)$ is not so exotic as it might first appear - in particular, it is (isomorphic to) a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$.

There is a unique homomorphism $\sigma \colon \mathbb{Q}(X) \to \mathbb{Q}(X)$ that maps $X$ to $-X$ (namely, $\sigma(f(X)) = f(-X)$). This is an automorphism (as $\sigma^2 = \operatorname{id}$), and its fixed field is $\mathbb{Q}(X^2)$: Suppose $f(X)$ is fixed by $\sigma$. If $f(X)$ is a polynomial, then considering the coefficients of $f(X) - f(-X)$ shows that $f \in \mathbb{Q}[X^2]$ (since $2 \ne 0$). In general, if $f(X) = p(X)/q(X)$ is a ratio of polynomials, then $$f(X) = \frac{p(X)q(-X)}{q(X)q(-X)}.$$ Now $\sigma$ fixes the denominator, so it must also fix the numerator and thus $f(X) \in \mathbb{Q}(X^2)$.
Thus the extension $\mathbb{Q}(X)/\mathbb{Q}(X^2)$ is Galois, with Galois group generated by $\sigma$.

What do you mean by coefficients of $f$? It is a rational function.

@SteveD You are right. I have corrected the proof.

This answer follows Severin Schraven's ideas.
Consider the polynomial $f(x) = x^2 - X^2 \in \mathbb Q(X^2)[x]$. Notice that $f(X) = X^2 - X^2 = 0$ and that we have $f(x) = (x-X)(x+X)$ hence
$\mathbb Q(X)$ is the splitting field of $f(x)$. Since we are working with characteristic $0$ it follows that $f$ is separable, therefore $\mathbb Q(X)$ is the splitting field of a separable polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb Q(X^2)$ and it follows that $\mathbb Q(X)$ is Galois over $\mathbb Q(X^2)$.
Another way to see that $f(x)$ is separable is to notice that $f'(x) = 2x$ and that $f'(X) = 2X \neq 0$ therefore the root $X$ has multiplicity $1$
Edit: Since $f(x)$ is quadratic, it has two roots and these are $X, -X$ in $\mathbb Q(X)$. And we have that the roots are distinct, for example, we can evaluate at $X = 1$ and get $-1 \neq 1$ so $-X \neq X$

It is not a priori clear that $f$ is the correct polynomial. You will need to check that its roots in $\mathbb{Q}(X)$ are all distinct (which is not hard to see, but one needs to do it anyways).

I think I've now showed that the roots are distinct. Thanks for the help
